# i want to get user phone number after Facebook login in web

Tags: android, facebook, windows-phone-8

Could you please help me to know me, is this possible to get user's phone number while fb login in my website?

i have a SDK to get others data, like name, email, gender.. etc etc

**if**

$user->email = $me->getProperty('email');  // got email

$user->gender = $me->getProperty('gender'); // got gender

**then**

$user->phone = $me->getProperty('phone'); //got phone number ???

please help to get phone number

Comment: I think, it's not possible because phone number can be private so everybody cannot see it.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply ... #anshul Tyagi

Comment: Please read Facebook api documentation.For getting user private information you need to upload your app on Facebook and get permission.

Comment: Thanks #Jignesh Jain , i read many times get confuse..

Answer (score 1):

There is no `phone` field in the Graph API. You should have a look at the docs, then this would have been clear from the start.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading

Answer (score 1):

No, Facebook does not allow someone using the Graph API to fetch a user's phone number. There is no process to get a user's phone number from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

No, Facebook does not allow get a user's phone number from Facebook.